# Student dorms in Stuttgart (Germany)

Tags: germany, accommodation, study, stuttgart

I'm intending to spend 6 months in Stuttgart in Germany starting from June 2014, and I'm searching for student dorms to stay in for one month until I find a room in a shared apartment. 
I'm willing to pay up to 400 Euros per month. I've tried to ask in [Kolpinghaus](http://www.kolpinghaus-stuttgart.de/) in Stuttgart, but they don't have any free rooms left.

Comment: Just for clarification: will you actually be studying in Germany?

Comment: i'll be for a summer internship, but i'm a student

Answer (score 7):

Studentenwerk Stuttgart is the public provider for student dorms in Stuttgart.

As their website [states](http://www.studentenwerk-stuttgart.de/wohnen/kurzzeitvermietung) (sorry, only german), short term rental is possible, but has to be checked with each facility. 
Use the email addresses provided in my link, the dorm offices are usually run by students, so an English request should be just fine.

Please note, most dorms are located in Stuttgart-Vaihingen (south-west of Stuttgart), S-Bahn stop is "Universität". There's only one for short term listed in the city center (Max Kade Haus).

I used to live in "Straußäcker I", which I really liked, but that was 8 years ago :-)

There's also a [list](http://www.studentenwerk-stuttgart.de/wohnen/kurzzeitvermietung/kurzzeitvermietung-weitere-angebote) of other dorms, which may offer short-term rental.

Answer (score 6):

The dormitories operated by the Studentenwerk Stuttgart [give priority](http://www.studentenwerk-stuttgart.de/wohnheime-faq) to students of the local universities:

> May I rent a room if I am registered at another university?
>
> Of course, you may apply. However, your application will be considered only after all students from our own universities have their rooms.

This means, your chances are pretty bad.

However, they also operate an ["international student hotel"](http://www.studentenwerk-stuttgart.de/wohnen/internationales-studentenhotel) which seems to be exactly right for your requirements. It has shared apartment style rooms for 310 to 330 EUR per month.

The University's website on [temporary accomodation](http://www.ia.uni-stuttgart.de/internat/studierende/practical/accomm/temporary/index.en.html) lists a number of hostels as a (probably pricier) alternative.

Comment: OP has stated he wants only a short-term rental, so chances may not be such as bad as for a regular rental

Comment: @Simon: As students of the local universities will usually rent for a full semester (6 months), and each semester is directly followed by the next, I don't see how looking for a short-term rental would significantly improve chances.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I don't know the current situation, but while I studied there, lots of rooms where rented short-term, e.g. when the regular tenants where away for a couple of weeks for an internship etc.

Comment: @Simon: Ah - I don't know how it's in Stuttgart, but whenever I encountered such arrangements, they seemed to be inofficial, by the long-term tenants themselves, and not quite allowed by the dorm administration (albeit tolerated by on-site staff).